# GetPixel memory leak in Python

Tags: python, memory, pixel, getpixel

I have a script that sits outside a game, reads pixels, and reacts to that information by "pressing keys", "clicking", etc. So to get the pixels, I am using code like this

```
def function():
    a = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), x, y)
    return a
```

in order to get values of pixels on the screen quickly and have the script quickly react.

It starts off fine, is able to execute everything it needs to in time, but it gets progressively slower.

I have identified the problem source as GetPixel by trying to use other methods like this

```
def function():
    box = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    im = ImageOps.grayscale(ImageGrab.grab(box))
    a = array(im.getcolors())
    a = a.sum()
    return a
```

which are far too slow, but if I run a while loop containing these other methods, they do not gradually execute slower and slower like the fast method with GetPixel does (memory leak.)

I am using local variables that are deleted afterwards, etc. It IS GetPixel that is the problem. I just don't know where the stuff it's not deleting is, how to tell Python to delete it, if that's even possible, etc.

Comment: Have you tried storing the device content, i.e. `win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow())`, in a local variable inside your function and then deleting it after use?

Comment: del/gc.collcet can delete the object/collect garbage and you can also use gc.garbage to see if there is reference cycle

Answer (score 1):

You should call [win32gui.ReleaseDC](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32gui__ReleaseDC_meth.html) for each call of [win32gui.GetDC](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32gui__GetDC_meth.html) as explained in [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After painting with a common DC, the ReleaseDC function must be called to release the DC.

```
def function():
    hwnd = win32gui.GetActiveWindow()
    hdc  = win32gui.GetDC(hwnd)
    a = win32gui.GetPixel(hdc , x, y)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc)
    return a
```